# Get current user id inside shortcode return ever 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to customize a shortcode put inside a custom plugin, but I can't get the user id, it always returns me 0.

It might also be okay to understand the role with current_user_can, but any information is always empty.

Here the code:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'check_current_user' );

function check_current_user() {
// Your CODE with user data
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
return $current_user->ID;
}

function appp_hide_content_shortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
if( class_exists('AppPresser') && AppPresser::is_app() )
    return check_current_user();
else
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('appp_hide_content', 'appp_hide_content_shortcode');
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/#comment-2506 `You can use it from the plugins_loaded hook on.`

Comment: I updated base on your indications my code, but nothing, ever 0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
/**
* Hide content on app.
* 
* Use this shortcode to hide content when viewed using the app.
* 
* Use:
* [appp_hide_content]This content will not appear on the app.[/appp_hide_content]
*/
function appp_hide_content_shortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {

ob_start();

    //GET CURRENT USER ID
    global $current_user;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $current_user->ID;

    if (current_user_can('free')){
        if( class_exists('AppPresser') && AppPresser::is_app() )
            echo '';
        else
            echo $content;
     }

$sc_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


return $sc_html;
}

add_shortcode('appp_hide_content', 'appp_hide_content_shortcode');
```

Comment: How are you calling shortcode??
echo do_shortcode('[appp_hide_content]');

Comment: No, I put into post, to hide content like this [appp_hide_content]This content will not appear on the app.[/appp_hide_content]. It works and hide content, but not with my user can conditions.

Comment: Please try "$current_user->data->ID" instead of "$current_user->ID"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the user after the user is loaded. I would hook to `init`.  You can't call the pluggable functions directly in a plugin without delaying the execution.  The simpler solution to your problem would be to include your shortcode in your theme's functions.php, rather than in a plugin.  But below will execute.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'check_current_user' , 999);
function check_current_user() {
    // This returns current user id
    return get_current_user_id();
}

function appp_hide_content_shortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
if( class_exists('AppPresser') && AppPresser::is_app() ){
    // This is only returning an integer here.
    return check_current_user(); 
    }  else  {
    return $content;
    }
}
add_shortcode('appp_hide_content', 'appp_hide_content_shortcode');
```